# Gnome Network Configuration GUI is missing

Tags: networking, centos, centos6.4

Recently installed CentOS 6.4 on a server. I'm not sure if this is something that has to be specifically installed or not, but there is no Network Configuration GUI in Gnome. On other CentOS systems I've seen a Network Configuration window accessible via the System > Administration menu, but it's not there.

I know that I can make all my changes via terminal, but it would be nice to have the GUI. Is this something I can install via `yum`? If so, what is it called? What do I search for?

Comment: yum install gnome-network-manager ?

Comment: Did you follow: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Laptops/NetworkManager ?

Comment: A GUI on a server? There's the first problem you need to fix.

Comment: @AWippler I was missing `NetworkManager-gnome`. Feel free to add that as an actual answer and I'll give you credit. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelHampton I know. Sorry I'm not pro yet. For some reason our server was defaulting it's `nameserver` in `/etc/resolv.conf` to `127.0.0.1` no matter what I did. Installing this `NetworkManager-gnome` somehow magically fixed the problem.

Comment: @Jakobud I am stuck on the debian-based names. :/  In my experience, NetworkManager has its own configuration files and rarely uses the static ones you set up.

Comment: I didn't setup any static files that I know of. I just had the network using DHCP but it kept trying to use `127.0.0.1` as the nameserver. Maybe that was cause I have `named` installed (but turned off atm...)?

Comment: Why do questions like this get downvoted? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing NetworkManager-gnome

```
yum install NetworkManager-gnome
```